# Is this Bubble sort logic correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, bubble-sort

I saw some videos on youtube about list sorting technique, bubble sort and the code they used was

```
list1 = [4, 8, 5, 3, 1]

for i in range(len(list1)-1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if list1[j] > list1[j+1]:
            t = list1[j]
            list1[j] = list1[j+1]
            list1[j+1] = t
print(list1)
```

After taking different list and sorting them on my own without python i found out a pattern, and made slight arrangements to the code and i am getting the same output.

```
list1 = [4, 8, 5, 3, 1]

for i in range(1,len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1)-1):
        if list1[j] > list1[j+1]:
            t = list1[j]
            list1[j] = list1[j+1]
            list1[j+1] = t

print(list1)
```

But here, I just want to know if the logic is the same and the method also is bubble sorting cuz in future when asks me to do bubble sort, i dont want to do this and end up being embarrassed :p

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: One iterates from right to left, the other from left to right. They are both bubble sort, just mirrored

Comment: @MitchelPaulin does right to left and left to right have anything to do with ascending or descending order ?

Comment: No, that is based on whether you have `>` or `<` in the if statement

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Ohh okay cool :D then wats the right to left and left to right?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin What iteration are you referring to?

Comment: @superbrain look at the `i` loop.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin They're not mirrored. They perform exactly the same swaps, in exactly the same order.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's not the one doing actual work. That just provides a limit or the number of times the inner loop gets done.

Comment: @superbrain so both my code and the internet one are the same? which one is better?

Comment: The original one.

Comment: @superbrain after each pass of the `i` loop there is a portion of the list that is guaranteed to be in sorted order.  What is that portion?

Comment: @MarkRansom Some suffix.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why did you ask?

Comment: @superbrain I thought that the direction of the `i` loop would make a difference in which part of the list was sorted first.  It appears I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is bubble sort, but with unnecessary comparisons. You sort it by iteration over all n elements n times. But after the first time it is guaranteed, that the highest value is at the last position, so you only need to go over the first n-1 elements in the next step and so on. In your algorithm you just continue to the end. That does not make it wrong, but in is not that efficient. However it does not change the time complexity of O(n^2).

EDIT:
In reply to some comments: yes, in general you don't use bubble sort for efficiency. But there is a case, where it performs quite well (with the optimization where you stop when ther was one iteration without changes) and that is if you have a nearly sorted list.

Comment: The second version allows an optimization (not shown) that when you make a pass with no swaps, you're done and can exit early.

Comment: @MarkRansom you mean my version?

Comment: @CoolCloud yes.

Comment: @MarkRansom but is it efficient? he says its inefficient

Comment: @CoolCloud if efficiency is your concern, you would *never* use a bubble sort.

Comment: @MarkRansom  you are right, but you can do the same optimization in the first version as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom its not my concern, the code is just something i came up with on my ownSo i was wondering how good am i in python 

Comment: BTW what is the most efficient method to sort ?

Comment: @CoolCloud there are many O(n log(n)) algorithms (like merge sort). In average quick sort is O(n log(n)) as well but a bit faster, but in worst case it can be O(n^2). There are some not comparison based algorithms like bucket sort or radix sort that can do in O(n), but the only work for integers

Comment: @jjj if you dont mine me asking, what is O(nlog(n)) and O(n^2)

Comment: @CoolCloud Quicksort is generally considered fastest, not because it has the best big-O but because the constant factors are less - in the worst case it can be very slow.  Python itself uses Timsort.

Comment: @CoolCloud O(n log(n)) means that the algorithm only takes n log(n) steps (times a constant in the limit, where n is the problem size. So for example for n=10000 (list with 10000 items), c n log(n) is a lot less than c n^2, even for relatively large c. So the algorithm is much faster. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: nearly sorted works well for insertion sort, not bubble sort

Comment: @mangustaby nearly sorted I mean that all elements are near the position they belong to, not that most of them are in the right position